# Save the file in a different folder using python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, directory, path, save

I have a pandas dataframe and I would like to save it as a text file to another folder. What I tried so far?

```
import pandas as pd

df.to_csv(path = './output/filename.txt')
```

This does not save the file and gives me an error. How do I save the dataframe (df) into the folder called output?

Comment: did you try `df.to_csv(path = '../output/filename.txt')` ?

Comment: No, I get an error saying 'TypeError: to_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'path''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first arguement name of [`to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) is `path_or_buf` either change it or just remove it

```
df.to_csv('./output/filename.txt')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I still get an error saying 'FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory:'

Comment: I was able to save the file after creating a file called output